# maven packaging error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, package, scalatest

While trying to create `maven` package am encountering below error.

It facing only when I added `scala` unit test code to the existing project.

> Error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
>   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)

Am using below versions.

```
java : 1.8.0_131 and 
spark 2.3.0
scala : 2.11.8
```

Am suspecting issue from maven dependencies but couldnt able to find. Could anyone help in solving this.

POM:

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       
>           com-rxcorp-prdb-parent
>           com.rxcorp.prdb
>           1.0-SNAPSHOT
>       
>       4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.rxcorp.prdb</groupId>
<artifactId>com-rxcorp-prdb-scala</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
<inceptionYear>2010</inceptionYear>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>My License</name>
        <url>http://....</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <!--<scala.version>2.8.0</scala.version>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>${typesafe.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.rogach</groupId>
        <artifactId>scallop_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${scallop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rxcorp.bdf.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>loggingframework_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
        <scope>
            compile
        </scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <!--<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>${sqlserver.jdbc.version}</version>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-json_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.holdenkarau/spark-testing-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0_0.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatest.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--disable surefire-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.maven.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>



        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```